# Solving a recurrence relation

Tags: computational-geometry, recurrence-relation

I am having problem with solving the following recurrence relation. $A$ is a set, there are at most $k+1$ of this set and $|A|$ is at most $n/2$.

$T(n) = O(n log k) + \sum_A T(|A|)$

I guess it can't be solved by the techniques presented in CLRS book (like master theorem), I also tried to solve it using induction on $n$ (I mean the Computational geometry approach) but I failed.

thanks.

Comment: What is the computational geometry approach?

Comment: From what I know (and studied in computational geometry),  we can solve these problems by induction on their variables.

Comment: I don't understand your equation. What do you mean by sum over $A$? Which sets are you summing over? Can't we just assume the worst case, in which we get $T(n) = O(n\log k) + kT(n/2)$? For each fixed $k$, you can solve this using the master theorem. Even for arbitrary $k$ you can solve $T(n) = O(n) + kT(n/2)$ and then multiply the result by $\log k$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks for your reply. It is the *Lemma 4.4.2* in page 75 of the book **Geometric Spanner Networks by *michiel smid* and *Giri Narasimhan***. $A$ denotes a few sets and each set contains a few points. When I sum over the $A$ I mean number of $A$s which is $A_1 A_2 ... A_{k+1}$ and $A_i$ contains at most $n/2$ points. The $k$ is not a fixed number, it is a variable.The solution contains $n$ and $k$ variables which is most likely $O(n \log n \log k)$ (even though I couldn't prove it yet), but $k$ is not fixed.

Comment: Even for fixed $k$, the solution is $O_k(n^{\log_2 (k+1)})$ [correcting $k$ to $k+1$ in my formulation], which is not quite what you wrote. Perhaps there are more constraints on the sizes of the sets.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify the recurrence.  Right now it is hard to understand what you mean by that recurrence relation.  If you have clarifications, please edit the question to incorporate them and to adjust the question to address feedback.  Don't just leave clarifications in the comments -- questions should be self-contained, and people shouldn't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.